# Exact value of Elliptic Integrals.

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I was taking currently in a elementary calculus course where i found how to find arc lengths of a smooth continuous curve.

so here is how i started :

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1\Rightarrow y=\pm \frac{b}{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}$$By applying the formula of the arc length of a function, we get:$$L=4\int_0^a\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2x^2}{a^2(a^2-x^2)}}dx=4\int_0^a\sqrt{\frac{a^4+(b^2-a^2)x^2}{a^2(a^2-x^2)}}dx$$Now I made a little subsitution recalling trigonometry: $$x=a\sin(u)\\dx=a\cos(u)du$$So the Integral now can be expressed as:$$L=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}a\cos(u)\sqrt{\frac{a^4+(b^2-a^2)a^2\sin^2(u)}{a^2(a^2-a^2\sin^2(u))}}du=\\4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}a\cos(u)\sqrt{\frac{a^4+(b^2-a^2)a^2\sin^2(u)}{a^2(a^2\cos^2(u)+a^2\sin^2(u)-a^2\sin^2(u))}}du=\\4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{a^2+(b^2-a^2)\sin^2(u)}du$$So we have:$$L=4a\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1+\frac{(b^2-a^2)}{a^2}\sin^2(u)}du$$
Letting $m=\frac{(b^2-a^2)}{a^2}$ we finally get:$$L=4a\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sqrt{1+m\sin^2(u)}du$$

### BUT

later i found these type of integrals are known as elliptic integrals and can not be given in terms of elementary functions.

say elliptic integral of another type
$$u( k)=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin(\theta)}} \, d\theta  $$

---

expanding by binomial theorem or mclaurian expansion will lead to :

$$u(k)=\frac{\pi}{2}\Biggl[{1+\Biggl(\frac{1}{2}\Biggl)^2k^2+\Biggl(\frac{1.3}{2.4}\Biggl)^2k^4+\Biggl(\frac{1.3.5}{2.4.6}\Biggl)^2k^6+....}\Biggl]$$

---

### Now

### I am very much interested

in finding the values of these series rather than the arc length of ellipse.

---

I just found on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean#cite_note-BerggrenBorwein2004-2) where AGM method is used as :
$$u(k)=\frac{\pi}{2M(1,\sqrt{1-k^2})}$$

---

But

### At first glance

it is easy to see the following as a hypergeometric series :
i.e.
$$_2F_1\bigg[\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1;k^2\bigg]=\frac{1}{2}u(k)$$

$$LHS=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\bigg[(\frac{1}{2})_n\bigg]^2 k^{2n}}{(1)_n n!}$$
where $(a)_n=\frac{\Gamma_{a+n}}{\Gamma_a}$
simplify a bit
$$=\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{\Gamma_{\frac{1}{2}+n}}{n!}\bigg)^2 k^{2n}$$

---

But i really do not know how the values of hypergeometric series are evaluated.I have seen(of course in a basic way) some special cases of $_3F_2$ and $_7F_6$ but do not know what to do with those generated by ellptic integral.

Being unexperienced i will admire any suggestion from anyone.

please tell me how these elliptic integrals and hypergeometric series are evaluated.

### THANK YOU FOR GIVING YOUR TIME.

Comment: Have a look at the section about elliptic integrals in [my notes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxKdOVsjsuEwdjBEM1dpRkhMa2s/view).

Comment: By Clausen's formula and Legendre relation, $L$ at $m=\frac{1}{2}$ can be evaluated in terms of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$, but I wonder if you consider this *elementary*.

Comment: You may visit my archive page https://paramanands.blogspot.com/p/archives.html It has a lot of posts on the amazing theory of these integrals and related stuff. The theory is difficult and not exactly suited for an elementary calculus course but it's study is way too exciting and rewarding to outweigh the cost involved.

Comment: @ParamanadSingh       Thanks 'bhai'